# enable_if + type template, no SFINAE (enable_if_c without boost ?)

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, sfinae, enable-if

I understand from reading various posts that the following is not supposed to compile.

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <bool is_constant> struct A {
  // Need to fix this for g++-4.7.2
  // implicit conversion to int iff is_constant == true statically
  template <class = typename std::enable_if<is_constant>::type>
  constexpr operator int() const {
    return 10;
  }                                             
};

int main()
{
  A<true> a;
  int i = 2 + a;   
  std::cout << i << "\n";

  A<false> b;
  // int i = 2 + a;   // compilation error
}
```

Still, clang 3.2 accepts this code version and it runs fine. My understanding is that it uses an internal version of enable_if_c under the hood.
Now I want to have this compile under gcc which does not accept it.
I understand it would be good to have an actual type and use SFINAE as per other posts.

In my case:

- I am trying to define an operator, so I cannot fuss around with extra parameters that have some default type/value -> it seems I cannot use SFINAE.
- I cannot use inheritance either because I must keep everything constexpr.
- I cannot use any boost include in my code (enable_if_c) because of project requirements

Do I have a way out ?

Comment: What about `static_assert(is_constant)` ?

Comment: Why does `constexpr` mean you cannot use inheritance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not to use specialization?

```
#include <iostream>

template <bool is_constant>
struct A {};

template <>
struct A<true> {
    constexpr operator int() const {
        return 10;
    }
};

int main()
{
    A<true> a;
    int i = 2 + a;
    std::cout << i << "\n";

    A<false> b;
    // int ii = 2 + b;   // compilation error
}
```

this is quite straight forward and cross-compiler approach...

Comment: You know what ... why the heck not ? Turns out my piece of code has become so complex that I have lost track of this simple option... I have to duplicate quite some code since I cannot inherit (literal type and constexpr). But I can live with that at least for now ! Thanks !